# Multiple role for one User for multiple Client using Identity Server 3

Tags: c#, authentication, openid, identityserver3

I am trying to create Authentication Server using Identity Server 3. So far I could able to achieve use of Database to verify User, get Claim and get Scope and generate id_token for client.
Just to reduce number of lines I am going to display code with InMemoryUse, Here is my code

Scope Class:

```
var scopes = new List<IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Scope>
        {
            //For Identity Scopes
            StandardScopes.OpenId, 
            StandardScopes.Profile, 
            StandardScopes.Roles,  
            StandardScopes.Address, 
            StandardScopes.Phone 
};
return scopes
```

I am only trying to get only Identity Scopes with Roles, That is it.

Client Class:

```
new Client()
        {
            ClientId = "mvcClient",
            ClientName = "MVC Client",                    
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            RequireConsent = false;
            RedirectUris = { ..something.. },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { ..something.. },
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                StandardScopes.Roles.Name,
            }
        }
```

Now, here is my user Class

```
new InMemoryUser
            {
               Username="Admin",
               Password="test123",
               Subject="1",
               Claims= new[]
               {
                   new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Sam"),
                   new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Morgan"),
                   new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
               }
            }
```

And here is Startup class of Client Application

```
           app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44328/identity",
            ClientId = "mvcClient",
            Scope = "openid profile roles address phone",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                    // we want to keep first name, last name, subject and roles
                    var givenName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName);
                    //.. Same for Other Fields

                    // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                    var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        id.AuthenticationType,
                        Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                        Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                    claimIdentity.AddClaim(givenName);
                    claimIdentity.AddClaims(roles);
                    claimIdentity.AddClaims(scopes);


                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        claimIdentity,
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now my problem is, I followed similar approach for multiple clients and when I request authentication from `ClientA` it gives me correct information about user. But when start `ClientB`, good thing is it not ask for authorization but it gives me same role of `ClientA`. That means If `User1` is Admin for `ClientA` then it showing Admin for `ClientB` also where as `User1` is Tester for `ClientB`.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches

- Prefix role name for each client. In this case, it can be ClientA_Admin for ClientA and ClientB_Admin for clientB
- Store role infomation at client application database. Mean that, ClientA's db own role table. ClientB's db own another. In startup.cs You got Idtoken => UserId => Roles => Initialize ClaimIdentity include the roles you loaded from client app database

if you have some roles for all clients => store it at identity server db. If clients have some client specific role => store these roles at client db

The two above are good enough in most case

Comment: In approach 2, If I store Role information in Client Database then How will I map to which user has what role on that client?  Because it will give me all roles present for that Client. For Example: Client A has "Admin", "Tester", "Inspector" roles then it will return all roles together but UserStore will return only one user.

Comment: if you have some roles for all clients => store it at identity server db. If clients have some client specific role => store these roles at client db

Comment: Client's db you have User 1-------* UserRole *------1 Role

Comment: Ok.. I got one thing that I need to store roles in Client Db, but need to map with respected user.. Do you have any example link?

Comment: If I go ahead with approach 2, the how will I generate token with Role. Because I have to pass access token to mvcClient